# Typescript function output cannot be assigned to conditional type

Tags: typescript, conditional-types, function-signature

I have a simplified version of a more complex problem. The following causes TSC to throw errors:

```ts
type Demo<isTrue> = isTrue extends true ? { a: string } : isTrue extends false ? { b: string } : never;

const func = <T extends boolean>(arg: T): Demo<T> => {
    if (arg) {
        return {a: "hello" };
    } else {
        return { b: "world" };
    }
};

const out = func(true);
```

Throws the following errors:

```ts
    Type '{ a: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Demo<T>'.
    Type '{ b: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Demo<T>'.
```

The `out` at the bottom has the correct type on inspection, so just the function definition has the issue. How can I understand this better and how do I solve it?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhC2B7APASwM4BUBOBXCAfFALxQY75QQAewEAdgCbpTB7QD8UA3lAIYAuKOjap6AcygBfKEPLsqtBsygAzPgBt0nHlABGQkdjGSZQ+hABuEbAG4AUPYDGieiLW56TklGSZFdEwseoiIGhB89AQAFHzY4kKYAJRCcEh+RMRE3PZQeWSqULHxSTy5+RXYEMC42PQ8glAARAAWEBoaiE3SDhUy7dplFZXVtfW8Bs0A7ojYGozdUr35UvZLji5uwFCIuNukqp5O0Wz4SbZAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I understand this better?

Take a look at [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929) (also see the [original issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22735)). It boils down to the fact that TypeScript does not support the narrowing of function return types when using conditional types. Since the resolution of the `Demo` type depends on a generic type parameter `T`, it is the same as if you wrote the conditional directly in the return type annotation.

The issue should become clearer if we rewrite the `Demo` type (for demonstration purposes only):

```ts
type D<T extends boolean> = {
    true: {
        a: string
    },
    false: {
        b: string
    }
}[`${T}`];

const func = <T extends boolean>(arg: T): D<T> => {
    if (arg) {
        return {a: "hello" }; //Type '{ a: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ a: string; } & { b: string; }'
    } else {
        return { b: "world" }; //Type '{ b: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ a: string; } & { b: string; }'
    }
};
```

Now it should be crystal clear that `D<T>` remains unresolved *until* you provide an argument for the type parameter. That is why `const out = func(true);` is correctly inferred.

> How do I solve it?

You are pretty much limited to either using type assertions like `as Demo<T>` or dropping the generic type parameter and rewriting the signature with overloads as outlined in [captain-yossarian's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66311443/11407695) answer.

Comment: Thank you, I'm choosing this as the answer because of the links to discussions that actually answer my question as to why overloading is the only way to solve this and not conditional return types.

Comment: @aditya - NP, I remember sinking quite some time into asking myself the same question before stumbling upon the discussion. An unfortunate design limitation and looks like something that will be reconsidered in the long run ( after all, the inference *does* work here )

Answer (score 2):

I added overloadings and `Demo<boolean>` as a return type.

In this particular case `T extends boolean` practically the same as `Demo<boolean>`.

But please keep in mind, generics are tricky. `extends` does not mean `equal`.

```js
type Demo<isTrue> = isTrue extends true ? { a: string } : isTrue extends false ? { b: string } : never;


function func(arg: false): Demo<false>
function func(arg: true): Demo<true>
function func(arg: boolean): Demo<boolean> {
    if (arg === true) {
        const a = arg;
        return { a: "hello" };
    } else {
        return { b: "world" };
    }
};

const out = func(true);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhC2B7APASwM4BUBOBXCAfFALxQY75QQAewEAdgCbpTB7QD8UA3lAIYAuKOjap6AcygBfKEPLsqtBsygAzPgBt0nHlABGQkdjGSZQ%20hABuEbAG4AUI9W56AY2CpE9NS9fJMinRMLOpahAAUfNjiQpgAlEJwSP4E9s5uHl4%20bv6Byixs%20ASR0bEJsAgomKnp7p7etSUx%20oiIGhB89OVJKHqt7Z1E3PZQo2SqUE0kxKSFEHE8I2PLrl4i-CT80Q7Ly9gQwLjY3ryCUABEABYQGhqI59I7YzI32ou7Y-uHx7oGFwDuiGwGkYDykT1GUns4Mcq3o60QuGAm0aczitiAA)

Comment: Is there anything that `extends true` other than `true`?  I think there's not, so in this particular case I think that `func` needs the generic or the overloads but not both.  Overloaded with no `T`: https://tsplay.dev/rw2Rxw

Comment: Sure, I just did not removed generic from the overloading